# When Jenkins uses a regex for branch names, does it build ALL matching branches or ANY matching branches?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that polls my git repository every 2 minutes.  (I can't use a post-commit hook because my Jenkins instance is not reachable from my repository.)

The job is configured to build all branches having a specific prefix: the branch specifier in the job configuration is `:origin/sample-prefix-.*`

The job definitely triggers when a change is pushed to, for example, `sample-prefix-one`.

However, if two matching branches are pushed within the polling interval, will Jenkins build both of them?  If not, how do I configure Jenkins to build ALL branches matching a particular pattern with a single job?

Comment: Yes, your job will build both branches. However, you should be able to do a quick test to confirm.